# Django : Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use user.set() instead

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am getting this error when I try to add the current logged in user into another relation as `ManyToManyField`.

```
TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use user.set() instead.
```

Here is my code:

**Views.py**

```
def add_to_cart(request , item):
    name = item
    size = request.POST.get("size")
    extras = request.POST.get("extras")
    c = Cart(item=name , size=size , extras=extras , user=request.user)
    c.save()
    return render(request , "orders/add_items.html" , {"message":f"{name} added to cart"})
```

**Models.py**

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
    extras = models.CharField(max_length=64 , null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User , related_name="member")

def __str__(self):
    return f"{item} added by {user}"
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015204/direct-assignment-to-the-forward-side-of-a-many-to-many-set-is-prohibited-use-e

Comment: instead of creating instance from model and then saving do the following, new_cart = Cart.objects.create(fieldname=value)   new_cart.user.set(<user_instance>). create will let you add or set M2M fields

Answer (score 21):

You need to save the cart before you can add items to the many-to-many field.

```
c = Cart(item=name , size=size , extras=extras)
c.save()
c.user.add(request.user)
```

You could also use `set()` after saving. Note this will remove any related users not specified in the set (although in this case it's a new list so there aren't any).

```
c.user.set([request.user]
```

Finally, are you sure you want a many-to-many field for this? That allows a cart to belong to multiple users. If that's the case, I would name the field `users`, not `user`. If you only want one `user` per cart, then I would use a `ForeignKey` instead. Your related_name `members` doesn't make sense either. This is used to get the carts related to a user, so I would expect you to use `carts` instead.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `save()` again after calling `add()` or `set()`? Or is that automatically handled for us?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare no you don’t have to call `save()` again.

Comment: I get **TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <myModel: strName>.**

Comment: "myModel" is example of my model in ***models.py***, and "strName" is the `def __str__(self):` example. In ***models.py***. I can only add one question every 6 months, that's in 5 months now.

Comment: @Alasdair I found the problem. I was adding the wrong model to the `model.field.set(listOfQuerysets)`. My model had a similar name to the one I really had to add. I figured that out when I saw in ***models.py*** that the ManyToManyField had a different model added to it, so I made a list of that model instead in a for loop, and added it instead of the wrong one at `model.field.set(listOfQuerysets)`, and the error went away.

Comment: Glad you figured it out 