# How can I resolve this error? TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I am trying to programmatically creating a bunch of db objects and auto-save them to the db using the code below. But for some reason, I get the error below when I try to save the object (i.e. Tender object). The line the triggers the error is tender_obj.save() in the save_tender_to_db() function. What could be causing this problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\PROJECTS\leadshub\tender_matching_engine\management\commands\scrap_etenders.py", line 8, in handle
    main()
  File "C:\PROJECTS\leadshub\Tender_Loader\etenders_scraper.py", line 52, in main
    save_tender_to_db(entry)
  File "C:\PROJECTS\leadshub\Tender_Loader\etenders_scraper.py", line 129, in save_tender_to_db
    description=container_tag[0]
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 413, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 718, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 748, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 831, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 869, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1136, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1288, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1241, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1241, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1240, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1168, in prepare_value
    value = value.resolve_expression(self.query, allow_joins=False, for_save=True)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Please have a look at my code below.

```
#This is the model that stores the tender.
class Tender(models.Model):
    tenderCategory = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=False)       #this field holds the tender category, e.g. construction, engineering, human resources etc.
    tenderProvince = models.ManyToManyField(Province, blank=False)       #this is the province the tender was advertised from.
    buyersName = models.CharField(max_length=100)   #this is the name of the Buyer e.g. Dept. of Transport, Transnet, Dept of Agriculture etc.
    summary = models.TextField(blank=False)      #this is the tender title as per the Buyer.
    refNum = models.CharField(max_length=100)    #tender ref number as per the Buyer.
    issueDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)     #date the tender was published
    closingDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)   #tender closing date
    siteInspectionDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    siteInspection = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)     #site inspection date, if any
    enquiries = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True) #this field stores details of the contact person, for the tender.
    description = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)   #this is the body of the tender. the tender details are captured here.
    assigned_keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keywords, blank=True)
    matched = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
    capture_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, blank=False, null=False)
    date_assigned = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    tDocLinks = RichTextField(blank=True)

    def check_if_expired(self):
        if self.closingDate < timezone.now():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-closingDate']
```

```js
def save_tender_to_db(data_rec_str):
    try:
        url_data_ls = data_rec_str.split(';')
        sauce_2 = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.etenders.gov.za{}'.format(url_data_ls[0]))
        soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(sauce_2, 'html.parser')

        # finds the container div in the html.
        container_tag = soup_2.findAll('div', {'class': 'fieldset-wrapper'})

        if len(container_tag) == 1:
            tender_obj = Tender(
                # tenderCategory=Category.objects.get(pk=1),
                # tenderProvince=Province.objects.get(pk=1),
                summary=url_data_ls[5].strip(),
                refNum=url_data_ls[1].strip(),
                issueDate=extract_date(url_data_ls[3].strip(), 2),
                description=container_tag[0],
                matched=False,
                capture_date=timezone.now
            )
            tender_obj.save()  #this is the line that triggers the error

        else:
            tender_obj = Tender(
                # tenderCategory=Category.objects.get(pk=1),
                # tenderProvince=Province.objects.get(pk=1),
                summary=url_data_ls[5].strip(),
                refNum=url_data_ls[1].strip(),
                issueDate=extract_date(url_data_ls[2].strip(), 1),
                closingDate=extract_date(url_data_ls[3], 2),
                siteInspectionDate=extract_date(url_data_ls[4], 2),
                description=container_tag[0],
                tDocLinks = container_tag[1],
                matched=False,
                capture_date=timezone.now
            )
            tender_obj.save()    #this is the line that triggers the error


    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print(e)
```

Lastly, when I uncomment the two lines below, I get the subsequent error. How can I solve this?

```
 # tenderCategory=Category.objects.get(pk=1),
 # tenderProvince=Province.objects.get(pk=1),
```

```js
TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use tenderCategory.set() instead.
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015204/direct-assignment-to-the-forward-side-of-a-many-to-many-set-is-prohibited-use-e) for an explanation of why you can't do `tenderCategory=Category.objects.get(pk=1)`.

Comment: I don't think the traceback matches the code you have shown (there is no comma in `description=container_tag[0]` in the traceback). Make sure you have saved your code, restarted the server, then copy and paste the code and traceback again so that it definitely matches.

Comment: But presumably your models are wrong; from the descriptions those fields seem like they should be ForeignKeys.

Comment: And you need to call the `timezone.now` functions when you're actually creating the objects - or, leave it out completely, since it is already set as a default.

Comment: I've removed all the fields with default values but the errors still persists and I've also rectified the way I assign values to M2M fields as per the answer to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015204/direct-assignment-to-the-forward-side-of-a-many-to-many-set-is-prohibited-use-e).