# Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use categories.set() instead

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

**This is my model:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_created_by')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(to=Category, blank=True, related_name='categories')
```

**This is my serializers:**

```
class CreatePostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    categories = serializers.CharField(error_messages={'required': "categories can't be blank"})
    title = serializers.CharField(error_messages={'required': "title can't be blank"})
    description = serializers.CharField(error_messages={'required': "description can't be blank"})

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields= ['title','description','categories']

    def create(self,validated_data):
        title        = validated_data['title']
        description  = validated_data['description']
        categories = validated_data['categories']
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if (title and description):
            post_obj = Post.objects.create(
                title=title, description=description, 
                created_by=user, categories=categories) 
        return validated_data
```

When I try to hit the API endpoint then it gives me the following error:

> Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is
> prohibited. Use categories.set() instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use emails\_for\_help.set() instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015204/direct-assignment-to-the-forward-side-of-a-many-to-many-set-is-prohibited-use-e) please atleast search the site before posting question.

Comment: It's not helpful. thanks btw.

Comment: But why, what you have tried after looking into that question and what error do you get?

Comment: The error is in my category field. When I try to add the category data then I get the error.

Comment: What error do you get? share full traceback.

Comment: My error is in the question's title.

Comment: Can you edit the question with what you have tried except which has already added?

Comment: Do you have more than one category inside validated_data? Can you please edit your question and show what you have in `categories` variable through `print(categories)`?

Comment: I trying to pass only one category data.

Comment: Seriously, I think you should make `category` field a foreign key as generally, posts are of one category only, then the current code will work. Or else you should at least pass more than two categories from html. Since `add` and `set` method can only be used for adding queryset either in loop or by *args.

Comment: suppose i have more than 1 category then how i have to pass the data through category id?